# After how much time page loaded

Tags: c#, web

I'm trying to create a code in c# to find how much time it takes to website to load. (Not in a specific web browser.) 
Can anyone help me?
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Unfortunately, we don't write code. What we will do is help you with any code you already have. So get coding, and if you run into any problems, we'll be here to help out.

Comment: enable `Trace` in your `Page` directive.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to record how long it takes to get the basic page source, you can wrap a `HttpWebRequest` around a `stopwatch`. E.g.

```
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(address);

    System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();
    timer.Start();

    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

    timer.Stop();

    TimeSpan timeTaken = timer.Elapsed;
```

However, this will not take into account time to download extra content, such as images. you will have to dig deeper to do that and the question had no code so i can not guide you anymore down that path. But this example will work well if you just want the source with minimalistic code.

> you can also log all this information if you turn on trace

If you have control over the ASP.NET page, you could turn on Trace. There you will get a bunch of information about the Page lifecycle( including time stamps), and other useful profiling information.

Turn on trace for a page in the Page directive at the top of your aspx file:

```
<%@ Page Trace="true" %>
```

Or dynamically in code:

```
Trace.IsEnabled = true;
```

Or globally in the app setting this in web.config:

```
<configuration>
 <system.web>
  <trace enabled="true" requestLimit="40" localOnly="false"/>
 </system.web>
</configuration>
```

you then can use a tool like [Microsoft's LogParser](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptcenter/dd919274) or any other to read the xml trace file. You could also use [trace listeners](http://trace%20listeners) within your code. Just another thought :)